# Как отобразить ProgressDialog

Tags: android

Есть 2 класса, 1-й содержит `listview`, а второй класс заполняет список для `listview`, примерная структа:
1-класс:

```
Parse mt;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        lstView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstView);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                R.layout.news_layout, listTitle);
        lstView.setAdapter(adapter);
        mt.execute(URL);
```

2-класс:

```
public class ParseNews extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
        {    
            ...
            publishProgress(links.text());
            ...
        return null;
        }
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... links)
        {
            super.onProgressUpdate(links[0]);
            MainActivity.listTitle.add(links[0]);
            MainActivity.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

и о проблеме не получается отобразить прогрессдиалог в `onPreExecute()` и в `onPostExecute()` скрыть

Comment: Cначала сделайте без `AsyncTask` - честными `Runnable`, а потом переделывайте под `AsyncTask` - иначе так ничего и не поймете.

Comment: не слушай бармалея :)

Comment: а вы что посоветуете?

Comment: да я нечего не понял, вопрос звучит типа: у меня проблемы в коде, посмотрите мой симейный фотоальбом...  покажи код прогрессДиалога, как он включается/выключается, как работает сейчас, как должен..

Comment: код та простой
static ProgressDialog pd;
onPreExecute(){pd.show();}
onPostExecute(){pd.dismiss();}
не работает при таких раскладах (без них работает нормально), а должен крутиться пока идет заполнение списка и listview, в общем вроде нашел свою ошибку, я получается запускаю прогресдиалог не с главного потока а с нового.

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте!
Увидел Ваш вопрос и решил помочь.

- Во первых никогда не используйте
     Runnable вместо AsynkTask  если
     имеете доло с UI, так как вы в случае
     если Вы захотите поменять какие-либо
     елементы, то получите по рукам. В
     Андроид, UI часть может менять только
     поток относящийся к UI
- Во-вторых, впредь описывайте проблему в более развернутом виде.
   Как я понял вам нужно показать прогресс пользователю при выполнении некой работы в отбельном потоке. [Вот тут](http://startandroid.ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/128-urok-67-dialogi-progressdialog.html)  приводиться очень подробный пример работы интересующими Вас диалогами.

Удачи в разработке

Comment: вы правильно поняли меня, я по этому примеру делаю например там есть строчка
pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
так вот выдает вот это: No enclosing instance of the type MainActivity is accessible in scope 
погуглил там многие решали тем что просто создавали экземпляр основного активити, попробовал так же не получилось.

Comment: я юзаю аннотации, потому уже не помню как там правильно работать с потоками, но для себя делаю так:

1. перед загрузкой данных у меня в UI потоке крутится ProgressDialog
2. данные грузятся в потоке
3. после загрузки в UI делаю ProgressDialog.setVisible(View.GONE);

и все

Comment: Сорри, а как с помощью аннотаций можно избавиться от проблем многопоточности?

Comment: 3Gern, ничего не нужно создавать, вы наверняка создали внутренний класс для собственной активити.

Comment: я этим пользуюсь 

https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/WorkingWithThreads